# PUN + Standard assets character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

So, I have 3 scenes a singleplayer scene, a multiplayer scene and a menu scene. When more then one player joins onto the multiplayer scene they both move in the exact same direction. The deafult PUN character controller does not work very well + the tutorial I am using uses the standard assets character controller (which I know is outdated). I think it may be to do with the photon transform view which is nececary for multiplayer wheras in singleplayer without photon transform view/photon view, it works perfectly.

I have tried Changing what is synced but when you exit and reload the prefab nothing has changed.

Please help

Here is a video of my prefab.

https://github.com/JimmyBinoculars/stack/blob/main/2022-12-04%2010-40-33.mkv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.